# Leitura de XML Java

Tags: java, xml, nfe

Estou tentando fazer a leitura de um XML em Java para pegar dados de uma NF-e.

Tentei assim para tentar pegar só o código do produto pra testar mais sem sucesso:

```
 public void testeaa(String xml) throws DocumentException {

    Document document = getDocumento(xml);
    Element root = document.getRootElement();

    Iterator<Element> i = root.elementIterator();

    i.forEachRemaining(element -> {

        if (element.getQualifiedName().equals("det nItem")) {
            System.out.println("COdProd: " + element.getText());
        }


    });
}

public Document getDocumento(String xml) throws DocumentException {
    SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
    Document document = reader.read(xml);
    return document;
}
```

Exemplo XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<nfeProc xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe" versao="3.10">
   <NFe>
      <infNFe Id="NFe41180710930674000149550010000005561136042494" versao="3.10">
         <ide>
            <cUF>41</cUF>
            <cNF>13604249</cNF>
            <natOp>Venda</natOp>
            <indPag>0</indPag>
            <mod>55</mod>
            <serie>1</serie>
            <nNF>556</nNF>
            <dhEmi>2018-07-31T15:04:00-03:00</dhEmi>
            <dhSaiEnt>2018-07-31T15:04:00-03:00</dhSaiEnt>
            <tpNF>1</tpNF>
            <idDest>1</idDest>
            <cMunFG>4115002</cMunFG>
            <tpImp>1</tpImp>
            <tpEmis>1</tpEmis>
            <cDV>4</cDV>
            <tpAmb>1</tpAmb>
            <finNFe>1</finNFe>
            <indFinal>1</indFinal>
            <indPres>1</indPres>
            <procEmi>0</procEmi>
            <verProc>0.0.1</verProc>
         </ide>
         <emit>
            <CNPJ>10930674000149</CNPJ>
            <xNome>COMERCIO DE PRODUTOS AGROPECUARIOS JSM EIRELI</xNome>
            <xFant>CASA DO AGRICULTOR</xFant>
            <enderEmit>
               <xLgr>AV PARANA</xLgr>
               <nro>996</nro>
               <xBairro>CENTRO</xBairro>
               <cMun>4115002</cMun>
               <xMun>MARILENA</xMun>
               <UF>PR</UF>
               <CEP>87960000</CEP>
               <cPais>1058</cPais>
               <xPais>BRASIL</xPais>
               <fone>4434481934</fone>
            </enderEmit>
            <IE>9048560455</IE>
            <CRT>1</CRT>
         </emit>
         <dest>
            <CPF>82726647987</CPF>
            <xNome>LUIS CARLOS BONOME</xNome>
            <enderDest>
               <xLgr>SITIO SAO PAULO</xLgr>
               <nro>S/N</nro>
               <xBairro>SEIS CASAS</xBairro>
               <cMun>4111308</cMun>
               <xMun>ITAUNA DO SUL</xMun>
               <UF>PR</UF>
               <CEP>87980000</CEP>
               <cPais>1058</cPais>
               <xPais>BRASIL</xPais>
               <fone>4488326605</fone>
            </enderDest>
            <indIEDest>9</indIEDest>
         </dest>
         <det nItem="1">
            <prod>
               <cProd>5409</cProd>
               <cEAN />
               <xProd>BRUCELINA B-19 30 ML (15 DOSES)</xProd>
               <NCM>30023080</NCM>
               <CFOP>5102</CFOP>
               <uCom>uni</uCom>
               <qCom>1.0000</qCom>
               <vUnCom>18.200000</vUnCom>
               <vProd>18.20</vProd>
               <cEANTrib />
               <uTrib>uni</uTrib>
               <qTrib>1.0000</qTrib>
               <vUnTrib>18.200000</vUnTrib>
               <indTot>1</indTot>
            </prod>
            <imposto>
               <vTotTrib>0.76</vTotTrib>
               <ICMS>
                  <ICMSSN102>
                     <orig>0</orig>
                     <CSOSN>103</CSOSN>
                  </ICMSSN102>
               </ICMS>
               <IPI>
                  <cEnq>301</cEnq>
                  <IPINT>
                     <CST>52</CST>
                  </IPINT>
               </IPI>
               <PIS>
                  <PISNT>
                     <CST>07</CST>
                  </PISNT>
               </PIS>
               <COFINS>
                  <COFINSNT>
                     <CST>07</CST>
                  </COFINSNT>
               </COFINS>
            </imposto>
         </det>
         <det nItem="2">
            <prod>
               <cProd>3997</cProd>
               <cEAN />
               <xProd>BRUSKY ADULTO  15KG</xProd>
               <NCM>23091000</NCM>
               <CFOP>5102</CFOP>
               <uCom>uni</uCom>
               <qCom>1.0000</qCom>
               <vUnCom>39.900000</vUnCom>
               <vProd>39.90</vProd>
               <cEANTrib />
               <uTrib>uni</uTrib>
               <qTrib>1.0000</qTrib>
               <vUnTrib>39.900000</vUnTrib>
               <indTot>1</indTot>
            </prod>
            <imposto>
               <vTotTrib>3.63</vTotTrib>
               <ICMS>
                  <ICMSSN102>
                     <orig>0</orig>
                     <CSOSN>103</CSOSN>
                  </ICMSSN102>
               </ICMS>
               <IPI>
                  <cEnq>301</cEnq>
                  <IPINT>
                     <CST>52</CST>
                  </IPINT>
               </IPI>
               <PIS>
                  <PISNT>
                     <CST>07</CST>
                  </PISNT>
               </PIS>
               <COFINS>
                  <COFINSNT>
                     <CST>07</CST>
                  </COFINSNT>
               </COFINS>
            </imposto>
         </det>
         <det nItem="3">
            <prod>
               <cProd>4544</cProd>
               <cEAN />
               <xProd>BAYTICOL POUR-ON 1L</xProd>
               <NCM>38089999</NCM>
               <CFOP>5102</CFOP>
               <uCom>uni</uCom>
               <qCom>1.0000</qCom>
               <vUnCom>98.000000</vUnCom>
               <vProd>98.00</vProd>
               <cEANTrib />
               <uTrib>uni</uTrib>
               <qTrib>1.0000</qTrib>
               <vUnTrib>98.000000</vUnTrib>
               <indTot>1</indTot>
            </prod>
            <imposto>
               <vTotTrib>4.12</vTotTrib>
               <ICMS>
                  <ICMSSN102>
                     <orig>0</orig>
                     <CSOSN>103</CSOSN>
                  </ICMSSN102>
               </ICMS>
               <IPI>
                  <cEnq>301</cEnq>
                  <IPINT>
                     <CST>52</CST>
                  </IPINT>
               </IPI>
               <PIS>
                  <PISNT>
                     <CST>07</CST>
                  </PISNT>
               </PIS>
               <COFINS>
                  <COFINSNT>
                     <CST>07</CST>
                  </COFINSNT>
               </COFINS>
            </imposto>
         </det>
         <total>
            <ICMSTot>
               <vBC>0.00</vBC>
               <vICMS>0.00</vICMS>
               <vICMSDeson>0.00</vICMSDeson>
               <vBCST>0.00</vBCST>
               <vST>0.00</vST>
               <vProd>156.10</vProd>
               <vFrete>0.00</vFrete>
               <vSeg>0.00</vSeg>
               <vDesc>0.00</vDesc>
               <vII>0.00</vII>
               <vIPI>0.00</vIPI>
               <vPIS>0.00</vPIS>
               <vCOFINS>0.00</vCOFINS>
               <vOutro>0.00</vOutro>
               <vNF>156.10</vNF>
               <vTotTrib>8.51</vTotTrib>
            </ICMSTot>
         </total>
         <transp>
            <modFrete>1</modFrete>
         </transp>
         <cobr>
            <dup>
               <nDup>1</nDup>
               <dVenc>2018-08-24</dVenc>
               <vDup>156.10</vDup>
            </dup>
         </cobr>
      </infNFe>
      <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
         <SignedInfo>
            <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
            <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
            <Reference URI="#NFe41180710930674000149550010000005561136042494">
               <Transforms>
                  <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                  <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
               </Transforms>
               <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
               <DigestValue>eBgQo1KZj/0m4GrTiqMZ3KPmM1k=</DigestValue>
            </Reference>
         </SignedInfo>
         <SignatureValue>XEPqu9honydrDj0LYZFnJbhGAx4CIhxZPyNh/9iyZzp4UD3zPP3oSh6y6tj9hD9Hltitv3tpK3VqtUgUddfTY2GFKQ9q0xrAm82bGhNzk2tGDed1HIMOb7uLaIOdb59oFkwnmoG4q4XgWuD1h8JZ1wscYo4gyBvUPyHV0QmwscszGivGYamqh0opEgpDaB8Gk/MyO1GWODCdmnETIGZULxS3XYw1PNZAnKfOCW8d6WkY3l8owQNR1WipA0HbTH95DBU0HYjl9/h/6fyvUc4ekEoWiUkAaVbm+XNIdjkbY+9nQAOoNlA7GKzava9J9cHPVuikFoAv+rjP6EGPZYua3g==</SignatureValue>
         <KeyInfo>
            <X509Data>
               <X509Certificate>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</X509Certificate>
            </X509Data>
         </KeyInfo>
      </Signature>
   </NFe>
   <protNFe versao="3.10">
      <infProt>
         <tpAmb>1</tpAmb>
         <verAplic>PR-v3_9_5</verAplic>
         <chNFe>41180710930674000149550010000005561136042494</chNFe>
         <dhRecbto>2018-07-31T15:04:04-03:00</dhRecbto>
         <nProt>141180128267723</nProt>
         <digVal>eBgQo1KZj/0m4GrTiqMZ3KPmM1k=</digVal>
         <cStat>100</cStat>
         <xMotivo>Autorizado o uso da NF-e</xMotivo>
      </infProt>
   </protNFe>
</nfeProc>
```

Teriam alguma ideia?

Comment: Você teria um XML de exemplo para que outras pessoas possam testar o seu código e as modificações que nele quiserem fazer?

Comment: Inseri na pergunta, é um xml de uma nfe, preciso dos dados e percorrer os produtos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro, o método `SAXReader.read(String)` que você está usando no `getDocumento` espera uma URL ou um nome de um arquivo (https://dom4j.github.io/javadoc/2.0.1/org/dom4j/io/SAXReader.html#read-java.lang.String-), sendo assim acontecerá um erro se você passar o XML direto (pelo menos foi isso que aconteceu ao tentar executar seu código).
Para corrigir isso, você pode usar o método o método `SAXReader.read(Reader)` passando um `StringReader` contendo o XML.

Exemplo de como ficaria:

```
public static Document getDocumento(String xml) throws DocumentException {
  SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
  Document document = reader.read(new StringReader(xml));
  return document;
}
```

Agora, para pegar o código do produto:

Supondo que o código do produto seja o que está dentro da tag `<cProd>` (não tenho certeza, pois não conheço a estrutura de uma NFE), você pode usar o seguinte código:

```
Document document = getDocumento(xml);
Element root = document.getRootElement();

root.accept(new VisitorSupport() {
  @Override
  public void visit(Element node) {
    if (node.getQualifiedName().equals("cProd")) {
      System.out.println(node.getText());
    }
  }
});
```

E isso irá mostrar:

```
5409
3997
4544
```

Você também pode pegar o `<det>`, com isso você consegue acessar cada elemento filho separadamente: (Útil para caso você precise acessar não apenas o `cProd`)

```
root.accept(new VisitorSupport() {
  @Override
  public void visit(Element node) {
    if (node.getQualifiedName().equals("det")) {
      String attributoNItem = node.attributeValue("nItem");

      System.out.println("Item " + attributoNItem);

      Element prodNode = (Element) node.element("prod");
      System.out.println("Código: " + prodNode.element("cProd").getText());
    }
  }
});
```

Saída:

```
Item 1
Código: 5409
Item 2
Código: 3997
Item 3
Código: 4544
```

Comment: Exatamente isso que eu precisava, obrigado :D